# Use of the noexcept specifier in function declaration and definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

Consider the following function:

```
// Declaration in the .h file
class MyClass
{
    template <class T> void function(T&& x) const;
};

// Definition in the .cpp file
template <class T> void MyClass::function(T&& x) const;
```

I want to make this function `noexcept` if the type `T` is nothrow constructible.

How to do that ? (I mean what is the syntax ?)

Comment: you may check with `std::is_nothrow_constructible`

Comment: I know but I never used the noexcept keyword before, so I wonder what the syntax is.

Comment: nothrow constructible from what arguments? The answers assume you mean nothrow *default* constructible a la `T foo;`, but with the function taking a universal reference I wonder if you mean nothrow constructible from the function argument a la `T foo{std::forward<T>(x)};`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Declaration in the .h file
class MyClass
{
    public:
    template <class T> void function(T&& x) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value);
};

// Definition in the .cpp file
template <class T> void MyClass::function(T&& x) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value);
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/N3KqHV)

But please also see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1782465). You (generally) cannot implement a template in the source file.

Answer (score 7):

[noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) can accept an expression and if the value of the expression is true, the function is declared to not throw any exceptions. So the syntax is :

```
class MyClass
{
template <class T> void function(T&& x) noexcept (noexcept(T()));
};

// Definition in the .cpp file
template <class T> void MyClass::function(T&& x) noexcept (noexcept(T()))
{

}
```

Edit : the use of `std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value` as below is a bit less dirty i that case

Comment: Technically `noexcept(noexcept(T()))` *does not* mean `T` can be constructed without exception; it means `T` can be constructed *and destructed* without exception. You need to use `noexcept(noexcept(::new (nullptr) T()))`.