# How to understand function code in definition folder?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

There is simple `max()` function code in algorithm file. Maybe it's c++ code but i understand nothing here. There are a lot of macros. Can you explain me how to understand this type of code? And why are there a lot of `#define` used ?

```
        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION max
template<class _Ty> inline

    _Post_equal_to_(_Left < _Right ? _Right : _Left)

    constexpr const _Ty& (max)(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right)
        _NOEXCEPT_OP(_NOEXCEPT_OP(_DEBUG_LT(_Left, _Right)))
    {   // return larger of _Left and _Right
    return (_DEBUG_LT(_Left, _Right) ? _Right : _Left);
    }

template<class _Ty> inline
    /* constexpr */ // TRANSITION
    _Ty (max)(_XSTD initializer_list<_Ty> _Ilist)
    {   // return leftmost/largest
    return ((_STD max)(_Ilist, less<>()));
    }
```

Comment: First hint:  template is c++ only; so it's not c (let me remove that for you before you get flamed for that mistake)

Comment: Sure. I got you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"HOW to understand" complex code, is simply walking through it, one word (or line) at a time, and understanding exactly what it means.  Often the best way to do this when you're starting out is to just find any `#defines` and copy paste them in place.

Taking the first example  (note this is HOW to work it out, not what it does)

```
template<class _Ty> inline
```

Ok, so we're looking at an inline template... I can look up on cppreference what they mean

```
_Post_equal_to_(_Left < _Right ? _Right : _Left)
```

Looks like a macro (because it's outside any {}) ... best find what that definition is, and post it in its place.  If it calls other macros (it does) then I'll have to repeat until I understand exactly what it's doing.

```
constexpr const _Ty& (max)(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right)
```

constexpr & const ... those I can look up at cpprefernce too.
_Ty&  well, I know from my reading of template at cppreference that this is returning the type that the template is based on; and we get a return value and a left&right.

Maybe I've not seen that syntax (max) before for declaring a function... And I can't find any documentation on what's going on; and I'm not able to understand / find the c++ standard.  I'll ask on Stack Overflow if it's valid syntax and if there's any reason to pick it over just `max()` as that's a specific problem which I can post the results of research about; but I know it's accepted in MY compiler because I've tried it.

```
    _NOEXCEPT_OP(_NOEXCEPT_OP(_DEBUG_LT(_Left, _Right)))
```

More macros - well, best find and paste those; it's actually related to another question [Use of the noexcept specifier in function declaration and definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837681/use-of-the-noexcept-specifier-in-function-declaration-and-definition)  So I'm going to read that to fast forward and save me time.

```
{   // return larger of _Left and _Right
return (_DEBUG_LT(_Left, _Right) ? _Right : _Left);
}
```

Well, only one macro to go  (because it's all capitals) but we've already seen this one before.. and the helpful comment says what it does.

To answer the latter - why so many #define - that's quite simple.  They wanted to.  They didn't need to, and some would tend to frown upon their continued use.  I don't think it's worth expanding on that point further since it's not going to help anyone.

Comment: I just don't understand why those 15 lines of code with lot of macros is better than this ?  `template<class _Ty> inline 
_Ty my_max(_Ty x, _Ty y) {
 return x > y ? x : y;
}`

Comment: 1. not 15; just 7 for the 1st function.   2.  did you do all the steps, because `constexpr` may have a big impact on performance here... you're still trying to understand why it's different, while not understanding what it all means

Comment: `template<class _Ty> inline 
constexpr const _Ty& my_max(const _Ty& x,const  _Ty& y) {
 return x > y ? x : y;
}` How about now ? Yes maybe i don't know everything but i know syntax very well. So i'm trying to understand point of macros.

Comment: Macros can change depending on other defines.  so DEBUG_LT likely does something different between debug and release builds.   How do they differ?  Well, I'm sure you'll work it out once you've found their definitions and expanded them.

Comment: `#define _DEBUG_LT(x, y) \
 _DEBUG_LT_IMPL(x, y, _FILENAME, __LINE__)`  and  `#define _DEBUG_LT_IMPL _Debug_lt`  Do you mean this definition? Where can i find explanation of this ?

Comment: just keep expanding.

Comment: "find any #defines and copy paste them in place" - a good IDE will expand for you, if you wish. For instance, Eclipse CDT will, if you just hover the cursor.

Comment: And, with the GCC compiler, "If you use the '-E' option, nothing is done except preprocessing". So, you can run your source through the compiler and it will generate source with all macros expanded. No need to do it manually.

Comment: @Mawg They likely only do the first expansion; but if it's a macro wrapping a macro, wrapping a function (like Debug_LT) then it doesn't help *enough*

Comment: "likely"? Are you sure? I would need to check that & get mack to you. There is always gcc -E, which I commented at the same time as you

Comment: @Mawg VS also offers the ability to do the same; but if you're trying to understand a single function in a large project, it can end up being like trying to break a nut with a sledge hammer